# How to find the position of the first occurrence of a pattern using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to figure out a way to parse an email.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to search for the first occurrence of a text that is in this format

```
> On Mar 12, 2015, at 7:47 AM, Mike G <email@yourdomain.com> wrote:
```

the text will start with `> On`  and ends with  wrote:

> On Mar 12, 2015, at 7:47 AM, Mike G  wrote:

How can I find that in PHP?

I could do

```
   $msg = strpos($msg, '> On'); // to get the first position
   $msg = strstr($msg, '> On', true); // with PHP 5.3+ to get the text prior the first '> On '
```

But I need to look for a similar pattern line to be more acurate.

I tried this code:

```
$matches = '';
$pattern = "/ On*<[a-zA-Z0-9._-]@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]> wrote:/";

preg_match($pattern, $msg, $matches);
$msg = strstr($msg, $matches, true);
```

But I am not finding any results in the text.

Comment: You are missing your delimiters! Choose one: `~`, `!` or `/`

Comment: @Rizier123 I updated my question. can you please look at my current code and see what am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it. If the whitespace is optional change the `s+` to `s*`.

```
preg_match('~>\s+.*?<([^>]*)>\s+wrote:~', '> On Mar 12, 2015, at 7:47 AM, Mike G <email@yourdomain.com> wrote:', $email);
echo $email[1];
```

If you want to be safer and require the 'On' as well...

```
preg_match('~>\s+On.*?<([^>]*)>\s+wrote:~', '> On Mar 12, 2015, at 7:47 AM, Mike G <email@yourdomain.com> wrote:', $email);
```

Comment: Thank a lot Chris.that did it.  can you please help me understand what does the expression mean so I know how to change it if needed?

Comment: The `\s+` means 'one or more white space characters'. The `.*?` means 'find everything until the next character', in this case a `<`. The `[^>]` means 'the charachter can be anything but a `>`' symbol and the `*` means 'any number of characters until a `>`'.